# Bootstrap collapse with dropdown issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I want to the dropdown to be displayed at the bottom of the NAV BRAND (or Nav logo on the top left) when pressing the menu button. But, it appears next to the button in mobile view and in the center. See here:

[image]

Below is my **HTML** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Tutorial</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- TOP NAVBAR -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MOCK WEBSITE</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PORTFOLIO <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">PHOTOS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">VIDEOS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">MUSIC</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- Container -->
    </div> <!-- Nav -->



    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>MOCK WEBSITE</h1>
            <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4>Contact Me</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Full Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="you@example.com">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-msg" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Write your message..."></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
                        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="navbar-text pull-left">Site Built By Andrew Vu</p>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-btn btn btn-danger pull-right">Subscribe on YouTube</a>
    </div>
</div>




    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgotten wrapper `navbar-header` to group brand and button:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MOCK WEBSITE</a>

   <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/wc72464s/)

Comment: Ah, that did the trick! Thanks, Igor! That's strange as I was following a tutorial online, it worked for him. Wonder why that is? I followed step-by-step, too..

Comment: @user3385997, one more small point) it's not the best practice, to write words uppercase in markup, you may to use bootstrap's class `text-uppercase` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/wc72464s/1/)